# Displaying string in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Yes there are plenty of questions like this but strangely no answer seems to work for me.

I have a description field in my model that I want to truncate in certain views so a different context for just truncating a element in my model seems overkill to me.

```
        @{ 
            string description = item.Description;
            if (description.Length > 10)
            {
                description = description.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
            }
            //Using HtmlString
            var s = new HtmlString(description);
            s;
            //Using Html.Raw
            Html.Raw(description);
            //Using Html.Display
            Html.Display(description); 
        }
```

Whatever I try it results in a error or displays nothing at all. If I put a breakpoint after the statement my string looks just like I want it, I just need to display it in my `<td>` element.

Comment: Try this: @{ string description = "your string";} @Html.Display(description)

Comment: Of course, just after posting this I found `WriteLiteral` and this seems to work. Still I have no clue why `HtmlString` gives an error and `Html.Raw` displays nothing.

Comment: @RenanAraújo that only displays a semicolon. Any particular reason you put the `Html.Display` method outside the block?

Comment: Using `@Html.Raw()` outside the block seems to display my string but it adds a semicolon to it. `Display()` does only show a semicolon. Seems there are plenty of methods that should do the trick but they all need to be marked `@deprecated` if you ask me ;)

Comment: Html.Display(description);  inside @ block will return a MvcHtmlString but you're not "printing" it in html

Comment: If your string has html elements you need to use `Raw`

Comment: @RenanAraújo Playing stupid now but, behind just a `@` it's also returning "just" returning `MvcHtmlString`, nowhere does it say it prints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Html inside `@` block will return a `MvcHtmlString` but you're not priting it in your HTML.

```
@{ 
    string description = item.Description;
    if (description.Length > 10)
    {
        description = description.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
    }

    Html.Raw(description); // Doesn't print in html. You are returning to nothing
    // var myStr = Html.Raw(description);
}

@Html.Raw(description) // Print in html
```

Or you can just add `@` before `Html.Raw(description)`

```
@{ 
    string description = item.Description;
    if (description.Length > 10)
    {
        description = description.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
    }

    Html.Raw(description); // Doesn't print in html. You are returning to nothing
    // var myStr = Html.Raw(description);

    @Html.Raw(description) // Print in html
}
```

Comment: Outside the block it ads a semicolon. Do you have any idea why and how to get rid of it? Your 2nd option finally seems to work properly, inside the `@` block with `@Html.Raw(description)`.

Comment: You don't need to use ';' after @Html.Raw(description)

Answer (score 1):

You included the display methods in you code that's why you have the problem. you should put Html.Raw outside the code block.

You code should look something like this:

```
@{
    string description = "sdasdasdasdasdas dasd asdasd asd";
    if (description.Length > 10)
    {
        description = description.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
    }
}

@Html.Raw(description)
```

Comment: Two questions: How do I get rid of the semicolon since `Html.Raw()` puts a semicolon behind it in HTML. And why  does this need to go outside the block? Seems to me `@Html.Raw(variable)` would be exactly the same as @{ Html.Raw(variable) }, yet it does at least print something outside the block.

Comment: 1. About the semicolon. Maybe you're typing @Html.Raw(variable); that's why tou have semicolon. Type it without the semicolon at the end. Like this @Html.Raw(variable)   2. @{ Html.Raw(variable) } will not print anything because Html.Raw is a method that returns IHtmlString so when you're in code block the method returns the right string but you're not printing it. In order to print a value you should use the methods described here http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c